# @Autowire returns null after adding Spring AOP in an abstract base class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I'm using POM in my selenium automation project, so there is an abstract class BasePage extended by a DerivedPage which is used for test method

The method which returns Webdriver works before aop was applied, but keeps returning null after aspect annotation.

From my view, spring aop proxy wrapped the primal instance of DerivedPage, which already init the Webdriver, and overwrite getDriver to get it. But it doesn't work as expected.

I know there are two inheritance: BasePage -> DerivedPage -> AOP Proxy, but can't figure out why it can't get the @Autowired object.

Example Basepage

```
@Component
@Scope("cucumber-glue")
public abstract class BasePage {
    @Autowired protected WebDriver driver;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    //driver found after remove this aspect annotation
    @TakeScreenshot
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
```

Example DerivedPage

```
@Component
@Scope("cucumber-glue")
public class DerivedPage extends BasePage {
    @FindBy(css = "a[href*=\"member\"]#custom-btn")
    public WebElement memberButton;
}
```

Example Aspect Class

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ScreenshotAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(TakeScreenshot)")
    public void take(){
        ScreenshotUtil.doCaptureFullScreen();
    }
}
```

Example Test Method

```
public class SampleSteps {
    @Autowired
    private DerivedPage derivedPage;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(derivedPage.getDriver()); //returns null, but screenshot was taken
    }

}
```

### Edit:

Here I posted a simple MCVE project to reproduce the issue
https://github.com/Cordifhyura/Spring-AOP-issue

result:

```
Testing started at 14:10 ...
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.6)

Starting ChromeDriver 100.0.4896.60 (6a5d10861ce8de5fce22564658033b43cb7de047-refs/branch-heads/4896@{#875}) on port 40627
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[2022-04-28 14:10:48.832] - 31332 INFO [Forwarding newSession on session null to remote] --- org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake: Detected dialect: W3C
Starting - enter holo homepage and click member
ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (898dda5b1132c26741c8f8db732c1dc1) **//direct Webdriver reference in Hooks**
base.PO.HoloPage$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1308317
simulate screen capture
null **//.getDriver() in pageobject**

1 Scenarios (1 passed)
1 Steps (1 passed)
0m4.255s
```

As you can see the driver is correctly injected to Hook, so it's nothing with the DI or cucumber. It just missing in the AOP proxy instance.

Comment: Based on the pseudocode shared , a wild guess is that your `Around` advice method is not returning anything ( return void ) . You will get better help ,if an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could be shared.

Comment: Thanks, just added a sample project for reproducing.

Comment: I didn't try to run the code . Based on a quick look , you should be returning from [advice method](https://github.com/Cordifhyura/Spring-AOP-issue/blob/main/src/test/java/utilities/aspects/ScreenshotAspect.java#L17) so that the caller of `getDriver()` method gets the `driver` instance

Comment: Got it, but which I don't understand is, why the Proxy requires a Webdriver returning from advice method, instead of taking it from the proxied PageObject instance?
After all I don't need to pass a Webdriver instance for taking screenshot, just add an addtional function on the getter.

Comment: Please read through [`@Around`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice) and especially on `proceed()`

Comment: Thanks for giving a hint, I misunderstood the usage of around advice. In my situation simply use @After is enough.

Comment: Not exactly , your usage of `@Around` ( hint : `proceed()` )  was incorrect . The body of `@After` is different and appears would suffice your requirement.  Do read the section starting with  - "If you declare the return type of your around .. "

Comment: @R.G, I think it makes sense to convert your comment(s) into an answer, then the OP can mark it as accepted. Otherwise, the question will be listed as unanswered forever.

Comment: @kriegaex , sure I am adding the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ScreenshotAspect](https://github.com/Cordifhyura/Spring-AOP-issue/blob/main/src/test/java/utilities/aspects/ScreenshotAspect.java#L10) is incorrect.

The `@Around` advice should have a valid `proceed()` as explained in the documenation section : [Around Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice)

Do read through the information section starting with "*If you declare the return type of your around advice method as void, null will always be returned to the caller,..*" as well to understand what could have caused the null value to be returned.